# how to disable '' Do you want to save password for this site' chrome popup in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

My chrome got upgraded to version 57 and now my scripts are not working because of save password popup.
i tried from chrome setting but everytime i run my script the saved setting doesn't work in new opened browser. any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```